# RegEx matches thing it should not match?

Tags: java, regex

I have a rather simple RegEx which does not do what I expect it to do.

I want a RegEx that matches single-letter strings if they are one of several elements that you find commonly in smilies e.g. brackets, colon, etc.

I stumbled into a case where a question-mark made my RegEx fire and I don't get why.

I am on Java 8 (Oracle) and have a Junit Test for my issue:

```
@Test
public void test(){
    assertFalse(Pattern.matches("[:;-pP8xXdD\\(\\)]", "?"));
}
```

It should evaluate to false, but it matches, why?

Comment: I think you need to escape the `-`. Otherwise, it thinks it's a range.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `;-p` part defines a range for ASCII characters from `;`(59) to `p`(112). That includes `?`(63). [Reference](http://www.ascii-code.com/)

To fix it put the `-` at the start/end of the character group (`[]`) or escape with with `\`.

Comment: yes, It should be `\\-` since `-` is a special character that denotes range